# PHP Array Conditional Short Syntax

Tags: php, arrays

Here is what I have, I know I can rewrite my conditional syntax but I just wanted to see if there was something else I can do with what I have.

```
$sleeping[] = ($a->day_bed == 1) ? 'Day Bed' : false;
$sleeping[] = ($a->fold_up_bed == 1) ? 'Fold Up Bed' : false;
$sleeping[] = ($a->murphy_bed == 1) ? 'Murphy Bed' : false;
$sleeping[] = ($a->trundle_bed == 1) ? 'Trundle Bed' : false;
```

I'm trying to test for an empty array or not and rather than an empty array I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
)
```

This never registers as "empty". As far as I can tell I need the "else" syntax on there otherwise it fails.

Is there something else I can use besides `NULL` or `FALSE`? Or any other way to format it? I like this format because I have around 600 of these and it makes it much easier to read. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should use `var_dump` instead of `print_r`, you would see that the array contains `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to change the format as the check for existence needs to happen before you push another element onto the array. This should work:

```
if ($a->day_bed == 1) $sleeping[] = 'Day Bed';
```

You can save yourself lots of work by automating this task, eg like this

```
$bedTypes = array(
    "day_bed" => "Day Bed",
    "fold_up_bed" => "Fold up bed"
);
foreach ($bedTypes as $key=>$val) {
    if ($a->{$key} == 1)
        $sleeping[] = $val;
}
```

Comment: Alright that seems just as clean guess I'll change it to that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use `array_filter()` with no callback to remove all falsy elements in the array:

```
<?php

$a = new stdClass();
$a->day_bed = false;
$a->fold_up_bed = false;
$a->murphy_bed = false;
$a->trundle_bed = false;

$sleeping[] = ($a->day_bed == 1) ? 'Day Bed' : false;
$sleeping[] = ($a->fold_up_bed == 1) ? 'Fold Up Bed' : false;
$sleeping[] = ($a->murphy_bed == 1) ? 'Murphy Bed' : false;
$sleeping[] = ($a->trundle_bed == 1) ? 'Trundle Bed' : false;

$emptySleeping = array_filter($sleeping);
if(empty($emptySleeping)) {
    // here code if the array is empty.
}

var_dump($sleeping);

var_dump($emptySleeping);
```

[See it in action](http://ideone.com/N6Mn04)